# How can I retrieve weather from location (Singapore)

Tags: php, arrays, json, weather

I have been trying to create a application that reads the phone longitude and latitude and form a yahoo query to get the woeid but only some location can retrieve and some return null.

My questions: Is there any way that uses range to detect the location and return a yahoo weather reading to the phone ?

FYI the location will be used in Singapore.

**update**

I have move on to use another source of data which return json but I am quite new do anybody have any advice on retrieving the first set of data.

```
{"objects": [{"weather": {"status": "rainy", "measured": {"temperature": 299.0, "humidity": 94}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-05T11:14:50.363156", "sun_altitude": -0.023066939786076546, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.955007, 1.339955]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/rainy"}, {"sources": ["meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "stormy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 5, "wind_direction": 230, "temperature": 303, "humidity": 70}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-05T12:00:00", "sun_altitude": -0.2204749584197998, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/stormy"}, {"sources": ["meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "stormy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 4, "wind_direction": 230, "temperature": 300, "humidity": 75}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-05T15:00:00", "sun_altitude": -0.9020349979400635, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/stormy"}, {"sources": ["meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "stormy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 3, "wind_direction": 180, "temperature": 300, "humidity": 78}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-05T18:00:00", "sun_altitude": -1.0881742238998413, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/stormy"}, {"sources": ["meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "foggy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 3, "wind_direction": 180, "temperature": 299, "humidity": 95}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-05T21:00:00", "sun_altitude": -0.48149800300598145, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/foggy"}, {"sources": ["weather2", "meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "stormy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 4, "wind_direction": 200, "temperature": 301, "humidity": 97}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-06T03:00:00", "sun_altitude": 0.9304330348968506, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/stormy"}, {"sources": ["weather2", "meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "stormy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 5, "wind_direction": 200, "temperature": 303, "humidity": 86}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-06T09:00:00", "sun_altitude": 0.502163827419281, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/stormy"}, {"sources": ["weather2", "meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "cloudy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 2, "wind_direction": 150, "temperature": 301, "humidity": 97}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-06T21:00:00", "sun_altitude": -0.48176679015159607, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/cloudy"}, {"sources": ["weather2", "meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "stormy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 4, "wind_direction": 220, "temperature": 303, "humidity": 86}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-07T09:00:00", "sun_altitude": 0.502541184425354, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/stormy"}, {"sources": ["weather2", "meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "stormy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 3, "wind_direction": 170, "temperature": 301, "humidity": 98}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-07T21:00:00", "sun_altitude": -0.48207923769950867, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/stormy"}, {"sources": ["meteoblue"], "weather": {"status": "stormy", "measured": {"wind_speed": 4, "wind_direction": 180, "temperature": 302, "humidity": 84}}, "location": {"country": "sg", "locality": "Singapore"}, "timestamp": "2014-06-08T09:00:00", "sun_altitude": 0.5029566287994385, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.88671875, 1.318359375]}, "icon": "https://api.metwit.com/v2/icons/stormy"}], "meta": {}}
```

Comment: start with [json_decode()](http://nl3.php.net/json_decode)

Comment: @giorgio i know is two object then a json array am i right ?